# Product of Prime-th Power

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove

> If  $m^n=a^pb^q$ for positive integers $m,n,a$ and $b$ and different primes $p$ and $q$ (with $p+q \neq n$), then each of $a$, $b$ and $m$ must be a power of some integer $x$.

Comment: $6^2=2^2\times3^2$.

Comment: For different primes $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks!

Comment: @Servaes You have $m=a=b=2$, and so $a=b=m^1$. So your equation isn't a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4^7=8^3\cdot2^5$ is a counterexample to your claim in which $p$ and $q$ are distinct.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the question. Please, take a look.